# How to add a counter to display an alertdialogue in android

Tags: android

I wanted to display an alert dialogue to update the version of an application if an installed version is older for first time and after every 5 usages of an application.
The following code to update version of an application.

```
try
    {
        PackageInfo packageInfo = getPackageManager()
                .getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
        String appVersion = packageInfo.versionName;
        String latestVersion = getString(R.string.version);
        if (!appVersion.equals(latestVersion))
        {
            Dialog prefDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle("New Version Available!")
                    .setMessage("Version " + latestVersion + " is available " +
                            "in the Android Market, please update!")
                    .setCancelable(true)
                    .setPositiveButton("Update", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                    {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
                        {
                            dialog.dismiss();

                            String url = "market://details?id=packagename";
                            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                            i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                            startActivity(i);
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("Later", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                    {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
                        {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    }).create();
            prefDialog.show();
        }
    }
    catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain a counter variable in `SharedPreferences` or `SQLite`.Show the alert and increment the value when app is launched each time.Once the value reaches 5,you can start showing the `AlertDialog`.You can put the code for `AlertDialog` inside an if loop to check whether the value is greater than 5.

Set counter variable in SharedPreferences like:

```
SharedPreferences prefs; 
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

sharedpreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 

editor = prefs.edit(); 
        editor.putInt("count", count++); 
        editor.commit();
```

Retrieve your counter value like:

```
public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs";
SharedPreferences prefs;

prefs = getSharedPreferences("pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
int count = prefs.getInt("count", 0);

//Check your count here...
    if(your condition)
        {
        //Code for showing `AlertDialog`
        }
    else
    //Do nothing
```

Comment: can add code here. I tried with sharedPreferences i got nullPointerException and app is crashing. While reading value of  SharedPreferences mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

Comment: Did u set default value in SharedPreferences?

Comment: yes using following code i set value to SP.   SharedPreferences mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
        editor.putInt(AppConstants.COUNT_PREF, 0);
        editor.commit();

Comment: Try debugging and check the value you are getting for the variable.NullPointerException is because you are setting the value wrongly.

Comment: Did you try this? Any luck?